# gRPC Server with SSL on .NET6 and OpenSSL

Tags: c#, ssl, grpc, .net-6.0

gRPC server part in .NET 6 also looks different, now there is no Startup.cs, only Program.cs and all the examples I found go through creating a new instance of the SERVER class. But what should it look like if I use .NET 6 (Kestrel)?

This is "server" default code with one sevice (MyTestService) of .NET 6 Program.cs

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddGrpc();
    var app = builder.Build();
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app.MapGrpcService<MyTestService>();
    app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
```

This is the solution for the client from the official gRPC documentation:

```
var channelCredentials = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText("roots.pem"));  // Load a custom 
roots file.
var channel = new Channel("myservice.example.com", channelCredentials);
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
```

But there is no server solution.

UPDATED - CODE FOR CLIENT for gRPC .NET6:

```
    string certificatePem = File.ReadAllText("clientcrt.pem");
    string privateKeyPem = File.ReadAllText("clientkey.pem");
    var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(certificatePem, 
    privateKeyPem);

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    using HttpClient httpClient = new(handler);

    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://0.0.0.0:5000", new GrpcChannelOptions
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient
    });

    var grpc = new Test.TestClient(channel);
```

Comment: May be this article help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates

Comment: and this https://github.com/damienbod/Secure_gRpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still configure the Kestrel like you used to do with the new "simplified" .NET 6 layout, like it is explained in the [MS Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0). So, for the server-side Program.cs you posted, you can just [configure the builder to use TLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates). For example, if you have a certificate "server_certificate.pfx" for the server in the default code you posted, configure the builder like this:

```cs
// the code you posted, but with Kestrel configuration
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

// configure the builder to use the TLS certificate
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
{
    string file = "server_certificate.pfx";
    string password = "P@ssw0rd!";
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(file, password);

    opt.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(h => {
        // Choose RequireCertificate instead of AllowCertificate if it is required
        h.ClientCertificateMode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
        // this checks whether the certificate has been signed by some greater authority
        h.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
        h.ServerCertificate = cert;
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<MyTestService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
```

---

Another option is to just use the old .NET 5 programming style for the Program.cs in .NET 6 (which I prefer), like it is [described here in the MS Docs for console apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates). An example for how this could look like is this [Program.cs](https://github.com/damienbod/Secure_gRpc/blob/master/SecureGrpc.Server/Program.cs) file, which can be found in the repo that @Mihal By linked in the comments. If you go back to the old style, you can also just write your own Startup.cs for the Kestrel like you used to.

Comment: Im updated client code (for NET6) and added your solution to the server, its great, but i have error on client -  Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. "No credentials are available in the security package" p.s. The server (VPS with Ubuntu) starts up and waits for a handshake, but the client gives this error, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: No idea, I only tried it with IIS on my machine with .NET 6, since that's what we are using, and there it works. The builder can be configured in different ways for different systems though, I would go trough [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates) MS Docs article  (which was already posted by @Mihal By), to find a solution for the system you have.

Comment: When you google your error, there are also a couple of SO posts and github threads, seems like a Kestrel config problem, maybe check those out too..